# multiple instance of class in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, class, audio

i have a function to load sound in main document class in as3,this function accept input link and begin to load this path for example same function :

```
private function loadSound(url:String):void{
    var req:String = 'sound/'+url+'.mp3'
    sound_path = new URLRequest(req)
    main_sound = new Sound()
    main_sound.load(sound_path)
    main_sound.play()
}
```

when this function call, sound object multiple start playing,how i solve this problem for play only sound class in this time ?

Comment: somewhere u have used for loop to call the `loadSound` function.

Answer (score 0):

Place this at beginning of your loadSound() function:

```
flash.media.SoundMixer.stopAll(); //Stops all music already playing
```

If you have this code in a keyframe make sure you are calling stop() to prevent it from executing the code over and over.

If you have it in a class file (.as) it sounds like it is getting called twice